# Calculate intraclass correlation (ICC) on each column and return a dataframe with results

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, psych, irr

I have a dataframe based on a questionnaire, all participants answer the questionnaire 2 times. based on this a dataframe with all participants and questionnaire items is formed.

The dataframe looks like the following, (each row is a different participant (with its unique ID). and  the item '_1' and '_2' represent data of Questionnaire 1 and Questionnaire 2 that all participants answered (twice). each item is an question, there are 20 items (questions)):

***edited df specific for icc***

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 20, ncol = 130))
# Add the column names
colnames(df) <- c(paste0("ID", rep(1:65, each = 2), "_", rep(1:2)))
# Fill the dataframe with random 1's and 0's
df[] <- sample(0:1, size = nrow(df) * ncol(df), replace = TRUE)
# Set the row names
row.names(df) <- paste0("item", 1:20)
# View the dataframe
df
```

From the data of the two filled in questionnaires per participant I am trying to calculate the ICC per item.

However, currently I can only perform the ICC on the dataframe as a whole instead of per item. I tried:

```
icc_items <- function(item, df) {
  iccc <- ICC(df[item])
  data.frame(
    model =iccc$Model,
    type = iccc$Type,
    lowerbound = iccc$"lower bound"
    upperbound = iccc$"upper bound"
    p = iccc$p.value,
    icc = iccc$ICC,
    f = iccc$F.value )}
icc_col_names <- grep("^item", names(df), value = TRUE)
icc_col_names_list <- split(icc_col_names, factor(gsub("_[1|2]$", "", icc_col_names), levels = unique(gsub("_[1|2]$", "", icc_col_names))))
icc_items_list <- lapply(icc_col_names_list, \(item)
                           icc_items(item, df))
icc_items_df <- do.call(rbind, icc_items_list)
icc_items_df
```

the above code originally was used in calculating a different test, but I adjusted it to fit the ICC, or at least I tried, but it gives me an error.

- How does one calculate the ICC per item based on the dataframe of a questionnaires, (with each ID having 2 measuremoment per item), and to preferably get the values per item in a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

<sub>Providing a solution for the new dataframe shared by OP.</sub>

Here, I am using `psych::ICC` which gives us multiple models. We can use `dplyr::filter` to only get certain Model(s). For example,  `%>% filter(Model == "Single_random_raters")` or `filter(Model %in% c("Average_raters_absolute", "Single_random_raters")`.

**Explanation:**

In this solution, I add Items as a column (`rownames_to_column`), then using `pivot_longer` I get the *ID##_#Measure* in the long format which then can be separated to `ID` and `Measure` using `separate`.

Then I convert `ID` to be integers by removing the word "ID" and using `as.integer` (`psych::ICC` needs the values to be numeric).

Next, I create a new column with `Item` and `Measure` which then will be used to `split` the data per OP's request to get one ICC per Item per Measure.

Using `purrr::map` I loop over each of the dataframes created by `split` to reshape them into wide format (only including `ID` and `value` (i.e. survey responses)). Then I calculate the `ICC` for each dataframe, and extract the `results` which is a dataframe with the information OP is seeking, calculated by `psych::ICC` function.

`Model` is included in `results` but as the `rownames`. I convert them to a column, and then using `bind_rows` I put all the ICCs into a single dataframe.

Finally, I select the desired column and assign cleaner names for the final output.

`suppressMessages` is used to suppress the warnings/messages that `ICC` function gives. And `as_tibble` is just a preference which can be neglected. `filter` mentioned above for getting only certain models should be added at the end (currently commented out). `Item_Measure` can be separated using `tidyr::separate` into two columns as well if needed.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(psych)

suppressMessages(
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Item") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Item) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("ID", "Measure")) %>% 
  mutate(ID = as.integer(gsub("ID", "", ID))) %>% 
  unite("Item_m", c(Item, Measure), remove = FALSE) %>% 
  split(., list(.$Item, .$Measure), drop = TRUE, sep = "_") %>% 
  map(~pivot_wider(.x, id_cols = ID, names_from = Item_m, values_from = value)) %>% 
  map(~ICC(.x)$results) %>% 
  map(~rownames_to_column(.x, "Model")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "Item_Measure") %>% 
  select(Item_Measure, Model, Type = type, 
         Lower_Bound = `lower bound`, Upper_Bound = `upper bound`, 
         p_value = p, ICC_value = ICC, F_value =`F`) %>% 
  as_tibble() # %>%
#  filter(Model %in% c("Average_raters_absolute", "Single_random_raters")
)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 240 x 8
#>    Item_Measure Model    Type  Lower_Bound Upper_Bound p_value ICC_value F_value
#>    <chr>        <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 item1_1      Single_~ ICC1      -0.731      -0.413    1.00     -0.595   0.254
#>  2 item1_1      Single_~ ICC2      -0.0521      0.0750   0.500     0       1    
#>  3 item1_1      Single_~ ICC3      -0.242       0.242    0.500     0       1    
#>  4 item1_1      Average~ ICC1k     -5.45       -1.41     1.00     -2.94    0.254
#>  5 item1_1      Average~ ICC2k     -0.110       0.140    0.500     0       1    
#>  6 item1_1      Average~ ICC3k     -0.639       0.390    0.500     0       1    
#>  7 item10_1     Single_~ ICC1      -0.731      -0.412    1.00     -0.595   0.254
#>  8 item10_1     Single_~ ICC2      -0.0521      0.0751   0.500     0       1    
#>  9 item10_1     Single_~ ICC3      -0.242       0.242    0.500     0       1    
#> 10 item10_1     Average~ ICC1k     -5.44       -1.40     1.00     -2.94    0.254
#> # i 230 more rows
```

##### New Dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 20, ncol = 130))
# Add the column names
colnames(df) <- c(paste0("ID", rep(1:65, each = 2), "_", rep(1:2)))
# Fill the dataframe with random 1's and 0's
df[] <- sample(0:1, size = nrow(df) * ncol(df), replace = TRUE)
# Set the row names
row.names(df) <- paste0("item", 1:20)
```

---

---

#### Original Answer:

Here, I subset the data to only get the columns that match an item name.

```
names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "item1_")]
[1] "item1_1" "item1_2"
```

Then I subset the date to only have those columns for `icc` calculations. The result then will be stored into a dataframe. I included every variable, but any variable that is not desired to be in the final results, can be commented out in the `icc_item` function. I also added a column for `Item` to include the name of it in the final results.

In my loop, I loop over the items by removing the counter (i.e. `Item##_1` or `Item##_2`) after the underscore and only keeping the item name (i.e. `Item##_`). That way, we loop over the items not every column.

```r
library(irr)
#> Loading required package: lpSolve

icc_item <- function(item, df) {
  items <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), item)]
  iccc  <- icc(df[items])
  data.frame(
    Item       = gsub("_", "", item),
    Unit       = iccc$unit,
    Model      = iccc$model,
    Type       = iccc$type,
    Subjects   = iccc$subjects,
    Raters     = iccc$raters,
    ICC_Name   = iccc$icc.name,
    ICC_Value  = iccc$value,
    R_zero     = iccc$r0,
    f_value    = iccc$Fvalue,
    p_value    = iccc$p.value,
    Conf_level = iccc$conf.level,
    LowerBound = iccc$lbound,
    UpperBound = iccc$ubound
    )
    }

do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(gsub("_\\d+$", "_", names(df)[-1])), 
                      function(item) icc_item(item, df)))
```

###### Original Dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 51, ncol = 41))
# Set the column names for the first column and items columns
colnames(df) <- c("ID", paste(rep(paste0("item", 1:20), each = 2), c("_1", "_2"), sep = ""))
# Fill the ID column with values 1 to 51
df$ID <- 1:51
# Fill the item columns with random 0's and 1's
set.seed(123) # Set seed for reproducibility
df[, 2:41] <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), size = 20 * 2 * 51, replace = TRUE), ncol = 40)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you for the help!  When I apply the code to my real df it gives all the same output/value's on the items, (which on the example df it does not). It however, does say the amount of subjects is equal to the participants (ID's) and the raters is 2 (3 in my real df). If I understand the concept of icc correct, the subject per item should be 1(for the 1 item it is measuring) and the raters would be the participants. Perhaps do I need to add a  transpose' "t()" to the code?

Comment: @demi I cannot reproduce the behavior you are referring. Try to create a reproducible example. Maybe using `dput(head(df, 10))`?

Comment: Yes the code worked on that! Please pardon me though, after doing some more research on icc's I saw that for an icc the raters should be in the columns and the rows are the items. I edited the dataframe to fit this 'rule'  (as seen above). That is i think the reason why the raters/subjects was off in the code. But the code does not run on that dataframe.

Comment: @demi Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253515/discussion-between-m-and-demi).